# Getting SSL error- tlsv1_alert_protocol_version in .net 6 grpc solution

Tags: ssl, grpc, .net-6.0, load-balancing, tls1.2

I have recently upgraded a .net framework 4.8 project to .net 6.0. This project hosts grpc services. The difference between .net 4.8 and .net6 version is that in .net4.8 we were using grpc.server to work as a server and in .net6 we are using kesrel to work as a server and injecting GrpcServices.

This project (after upgrade to .net 6.0) worked fine on qa env, but when deployed to UAT it throws SSL error: tlsv1_alert_protocol_version.

The exact error:

> SSL: error:1000042e:SSL
> routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION. E0929
> 10:30:35.767000000 16344 src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:1420]
> Handshake failed with fatal error

Few things to note:

- Our UAT env is behind a load balancer.
- UAT server is Windows Server
  2016

I do not have any clue, what might be going wrong over here and how to troubleshoot this. So any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you need to see what versions of TLS are supported by the server and client. this error generally indicates one is requesting/providing a TLS version that the other doesn't support. Should be minimum TLS 1.2 now (with weak ciphers removed) but preferred to have TLS 1.3 support.

Comment: our UAT servers are already supporting TLS 1.2, and on clients we do not have control on. They might use older version of TLS. However, this issue is coming even if I am trying to connect using TLS 1.2